# SMD marking code WBDCD

Tags: identification

It is a SOT-23-6, probably a voltage regulator, used in a 3.3V controlled suction pump (Elephant Robotics [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09PH8YCVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09PH8YCVM)). They had the cable wired backward, so I think that is why it blew.

[image: Blown IC looking to identify and replace]

Marking seems to be "WBDCD". Google isn't being helpful. Any chance of identifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with how Silergy marks their devices so by searching, "Silergy SOT23-6 WB marking", I was able to find out that it is the [SY8120](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081220_Silergy-Corp-SY8120B1ABC_C88474.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Thank you!!